# Problem Connection SQL Server for Class in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, python-2.7

I´m not getting connected to database. Failure occurs on the connection:

when I perform the class call, I can not solve the pyodbc giving the error below:

This is a class in file Conn_BancoDeDados.py

```
class Conn_BancoDeDados:
    def connect():

        server = 'tcp:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' 
        database = 'DB' 
        username = 'user' 
        password = '@pass' 
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
        cur = cnxn.cursor()
        return cur
```

This is a call the connection and Query for getting the datas.

```
import pyodbc
from  CONNECT import Conn_BancoDeDados
```

#

```
    conn = Conn_BancoDeDados.connect()

    conn.execute("SELECT IP FROM TB_SERVIDORES WHERE TIPO = 'PRODUCAO'")

    for row in conn.fetchall():
        print(row)
    conn.close()
```

This is a faill:

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-902c042ad375> in <module>()
----> 1 conn = Conn_BancoDeDados.connect()
      2 
      3 conn.execute("SELECT IP FROM TB_SERVIDORES")
      4 
      5 for row in conn.fetchall():

~\Phyton - datascience\CONNECT.py in connect()
      7         username = 'users'
      8         password = '@pass'
----> 9         cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
     10         cur = cnxn.cursor()
     11         return cur

NameError: name 'pyodbc' is not defined
```

---

What´s wrong?

Comment: have you imported pyodbc correctly?

Comment: yes, i imported.

Comment: Do you have this import statement `import pyodbc` ?

Comment: yes, I imported.
My problem is when I call the connection file.

import pyodbc
from CONNECT import Conn_BancoDeDados

conn = Conn_BancoDeDados.connect() conn.execute("SELECT IP FROM TB_SERVIDORES") for row in conn.fetchall(): print(row) conn.close()

Comment: can you edit the post to reflect what you have imported and what is causing the error.

Comment: post edited ...

Comment: You are importing pyodbc at wrong place. import where you are actually using that is in `def connect` function.

Comment: No, I´m not imported in class. This is before for code the call.
Post edited with code complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, before invoking any SQL-related functions, do the following: `import pyodbc`.

You need to import a package before you can use any of its functionality (which you are trying to do).

Comment: is already imported. I did not put the imports here in the code.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Not solved my problem.
when I change to fetch the connection via file "entity", it happens the above failure.

Comment: from  CONNECT import Conn_BancoDeDados

Comment: conn = Conn_BancoDeDados.connect()

conn.execute("SELECT IP FROM TB_SERVIDORES")

for row in conn.fetchall():
    print(row)
      
conn.close()

Comment: That is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @mad_ At the end of the author's question, they asked "What's wrong?" This is an answer to their question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the import done at the .py file and inside that my class which I then import to the .py I'm working on with a "from file import class" and it works.
I think if you only have it inside the class which is in another .py file from which you are importing, if you also import pyodbc in the current .py you are working on then it works.